# 5941 - Multiple Errors - Set LocA_BldgRoomFlr = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocA_BldgRoomFlr").Range

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error

It seems I have multiple errors and I have changed code and done troubleshooting but still does not seem to work....I would GREATLY appreciate your help.

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
    Dim Ckt_Speed As Range
    Set Ckt_Speed = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Ckt_Speed").Range
    Ckt_Speed.Text = Me.Ckt_Speed.Value
    Dim LocA_StreetAdd As Range
    Set LocA_StreetAdd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocA_StreetAdd").Range
    LocA_StreetAdd.Text = Me.LocA_StreetAdd.Value
    Dim LocA_BldgRoomFlr As Range
    Set LocA_BldgRoomFlr = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocA_BldgRoomFlr").Range
    LocA_BldgRoomFlr.Text = Me.LocA_BldgRoomFlr.Value
    Dim LocA_CityStateZip As Range
    Set LocA_CityStateZip = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocA_CityStateZip").Range
    LocA_CityStateZip.Text = Me.LocA_CityStateZip.Value
    Dim LocA_NPA_NXX As Range
    Set LocA_NPA_NXX = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocA_NPA_NXXA").Range
    LocA_NPA_NXX.Text = Me.LocA_NPA_NXX.Value
    Dim LocA_ConnType As Range
    Set LocA_ConnType = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocA_ConnectionType").Range
    LocA_ConnType.Text = Me.LocA_ConnType.Value
    Dim LocZ_StreetAdd As Range
    Set LocZ_StreetAdd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocZ_StreetAddress").Range
    LocZ_StreetAdd.Text = Me.LocZ_StreetAdd.Value
    Dim LocZ_BldgRmFlr As Range
    Set LocZ_BldgRmFlr = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocZ_BldgRmFloor").Range
    LocZ_BldgRmFlr.Text = Me.LocZ_BldgRmFlr.Value
    Dim LocZ_CityStateZip As Range
    Set LocZ_CityStateZip = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocZ_CityStateZipCode").Range
    LocZ_CityStateZip.Text = Me.LocZ_CityStateZip.Value
    Dim LocZ_NPA_NXX As Range
    Set LocZ_NPA_NXX = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocZ_NPA_NXXZ").Range
    LocZ_NPA_NXX.Text = Me.LocZ_NPA_NXX.Value
    Dim LocZ_ConnType As Range
    Set LocZ_ConnType = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocZ_ConnectionType").Range
    LocZ_ConnType.Text = Me.LocZ_ConnType.Value
    Dim Circuit_Speed As Range
    Dim LocA_StreetAddress As Range
    Dim LocA_BldgRoomFloor As Range
    Dim LocA_CityStateZipCode As Range
    Dim LocA_NPA_NXXA As Range
    Dim LocA_ConnectionType As Range
    Dim LocZ_StreetAddress As Range
    Dim LocZ_BldgRmFloor As Range
    Dim LocZ_CityStateZipCode As Range
    Dim LocZ_NPA_NXXZ As Range
    Dim LocZ_ConnectionType As Range
    Set Ckt_Speed = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Circuit_Speed").Range
    Set LocA_StreetAdd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocA_StreetAddress").Range
    Set LocA_BldgRoomFlr = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocA_BldgRoomFloor").Range
    Set LocA_CityStateZip = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocA_CityStateZipCode").Range
    Set LocA_NPA_NXX = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocA_NPA_NXXA").Range
    Set LocA_ConnType = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocA_ConnectionType").Range
    Set LocZ_StreetAdd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocZ_StreetAddress").Range
    Set LocZ_BldgRmFlr = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocZ_BldgRmFloor").Range
    Set LocZ_CityStateZip = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocZ_CityStateZipCode").Range
    Set LocZ_NPA_NXX = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocZ_NPA_NXXZ").Range
    Set LocZ_ConnType = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("LocZ_ConnectionType").Range
    Ckt_Speed.Text = Me.Ckt_Speed.Value
    LocA_StreetAdd.Text = Me.LocA_StreetAdd.Value
    LocA_BldgRoomFlr.Text = Me.LocA_BldgRoomFlr.Value
    LocA_CityStateZip.Text = Me.LocA_CityStateZip.Value
    LocA_NPA_NXX.Text = Me.LocA_NPA_NXX.Value
    LocA_ConnType.Text = Me.LocA_ConnType.Value
    LocZ_StreetAdd.Text = Me.LocZ_StreetAdd.Value
    LocZ_BldgRmFlr.Text = Me.LocZ_BldgRmFlr.Value
    LocZ_CityStateZip.Text = Me.LocZ_CityStateZip.Value
    LocZ_NPA_NXX.Text = Me.LocZ_NPA_NXX.Value
    LocZ_ConnType.Text = Me.LocZ_ConnType.Value
    Me.Repaint
    PLS_CKT_Form.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error being reported.

Answer (score 0):

As the syntax of your code looks correct the most likely cause of errors is that the bookmarks don't exist.

The safe way to work with bookmarks is to check that the bookmark exists before attempting to write to it. The routine below safely sets the text and re-instates the bookmark afterward to enclose the inserted text.

```
Public Sub InsertIntoBookmark(bookmarkName As String, text As String, _
   Optional targetDoc As Document = Nothing)
   Dim bookmarkRange As Range
   Dim cleanupRequired As Boolean

   If targetDoc Is Nothing Then
      Set targetDoc = ActiveDocument
      cleanupRequired = True
   End If

   If targetDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName) Then
      Set bookmarkRange = targetDoc.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range
      bookmarkRange.text = text
      targetDoc.Bookmarks.Add bookmarkName, bookmarkRange
   End If
   
   Set bookmarkRange = Nothing
   If cleanupRequired Then Set targetDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Usage

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
    InsertIntoBookmark "Ckt_Speed", Me.Ckt_Speed.Value
    InsertIntoBookmark "LocA_StreetAdd", Me.LocA_StreetAdd.Value
    ...
End sub
```